# NoReverseMatch in Django when using foreignkey field lookup

Tags: django

I am new to Django, and I am writing a sysinfo app that lists users lab devices.
The "owner" view shows a table of all of the devices assigned to the user.  Each device in the table has a link to another page that resets some data, and redirects back to the owner page.

sysinfo/models.py

```
class Lab_setup(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Lab_setup)
    ...
```

sysinfo/urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<owner>[-\w]+)/$', views.owner, name='owner'),    # /lab/username
url(r'^(?P<owner>[-\w]+)/(?P<name>[-\w\d]+)/refresh/$', views.refresh, name='refresh'), # /lab/username/devicename/refresh
```

sysinfo/views.py

```
def owner(request, owner):
    device_list = get_list_or_404(Device.objects.order_by('col_order'), owner__owner=owner, active=True)
    return render(request, 'sysinfo/lab_owner.html', {'device_list': device_list})

def refresh(request, owner, name):
    device = get_object_or_404(Device, name=name, owner__owner=owner)
    device.last_ts = None
    device.refresh_count = 0
    device.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sysinfo:owner', kwargs={'owner__owner':owner}))
```

The 'owner' page works fine, and shows all of the user's devices.  The URL looks like "/lab/username/".  When you click on the link, it takes you to the URL "/lab/username/devicename/refresh".  The page that loads shows the error:

```
Reverse for 'owner' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'owner__owner': u'username'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'lab/(?P<owner>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

I don't know why the owner__owner doesn't work for the reverse, when it works fine for the get_list_or_404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's because your keyword argument is `owner` and not `owner__owner`

change this to:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sysinfo:owner', kwargs={'owner':owner}))
```

that should work.

== EDIT ==

The reverse util function looks for, in that case, a URL which name is `owner` under namespace `sysinfo` as you did. And it looks for that URL that expects to get the named arguments you passed in the `kwargs` dict.

You URL conf says it expects the keyword `owner` in the parameters passed to it. This is why you need to pass the `owner` keyword..

Regarding the fact that this stands for a lookup field etc - this doesn't matter because it is just a logical thing for us human.. all the URL configuration expects is the keyword itself to match the given regular expression written in its definition. You could just as easily pass `{"owner": "abc"}` and that would find the url and view to call (maybe your logic inside the view would fail because you'd expect a valid owner, but that's another matter).

The `get_object_or_404` on the other hand builds a query and you want there the object (`Device`) whose `Lab_setup` foreign key's `owner` ***field*** has a certain value and this is why you are looking *though* the relation: `owner__owner` .

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Awesome, that did it!  Can you explain why it needed that?  The owner field is a ForeignKey, so I thought you need the owner__owner to follow the ForeignKey back to the mapped table.

Comment: I edited the original answer with a little explanation. I hope that makes things clearer..

Comment: Great explanation.  That makes it much clearer.  Thanks!